# External Javascript math not updating correctly in HTML

Tags: javascript

Okay so I'm wokring on this assignment. I have almost all of it done. I needed to add text input boxes and have a function that totals the customers items into an estimate.I have all of the code, but no matter what numbers I have in my boxes on my "estimate.htm" page it ALWAYS returns 0.

```js
var blanketFlowerPrice = 15;
var hedgeRosePrice = 20.25;
var littleBluestemPrice = 8.95;

var numBlanketFlowers = Number(document.getElementById("blanketflower").value);
var numHedgeRose = Number(document.getElementById("hedgerose").value);
var numLittleBluestem = Number(document.getElementById("littlebluestem").value);



function getEstimate() {

  var total = (numBlanketFlowers * blanketFlowerPrice) + (numHedgeRose * hedgeRosePrice) + (numLittleBluestem * littleBluestemPrice);

  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--
          JavaScript 6th Edition
          Chapter 1
          Chapter case
    
          Tinley Xeriscapes
          Plants web page
          Author: 
          Date:  
    
          Filename: plants.htm
       -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Tinley Xeriscapes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 999px)" href="tinleyhand.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1000px)" href="tinley.css" />
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="tinley.css" />
       <![endif]-->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lily+Script+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <h1>
        tinley xeriscapes
      </h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Xeriscaping</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Plants</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">See Our Work</a></li>
        <li id="currentpage"><a href="estimate.htm">Get An Estimate</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>


    <article style="color:white; text-align:left">
      <figure>
        <figcaption>
          <br>
          <br>



          <form>
            <input type="number" id="blanketflower" value="0" /> <p> Blanket Flower</p>

            <input type="number" id="hedgerose" value="0" /> <p> Hedge Rose</p>

            <input type="number" id="littlebluestem" value="0"  /> <p> Little Bluestem</p>
          </form>
          <button type="button" id="getEstimate" onclick="getEstimate()">Get Estimate</button>
          <br>
          <br>
          <p id="total"> test </p>



        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </article>

    <footer>
      <p>Tinley Xeriscapes &bull; Tinley Park, IL 60477</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script src=src.js></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried a few combinations of code and none are working, could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? If so what are they? Have you checked the external script is in the expected location and is being loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are not getting the current values of the input. Put the code where you get the values inside the function like this

```
function getEstimate(){
    var numBlanketFlowers = Number(document.getElementById("blanketflower").value);
    var numHedgeRose = Number(document.getElementById("hedgerose").value);
    var numLittleBluestem = Number(document.getElementById("littlebluestem").value);

    var total = (numBlanketFlowers * blanketFlowerPrice) + (numHedgeRose * hedgeRosePrice) + (numLittleBluestem * littleBluestemPrice);

    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}
```

Comment: Wow I LITERALLY stared at this for 3 hours. Thank you a ton.

Comment: To add to this: you're grabbing the values of the input boxes when the script loads (as the declarations are uncontained within a function). Moving these to function runtime will grab the current values when the function is invoked.

Comment: Glad I could help :)